# In Java, how to do a nested Map<String, Object> with unlimited depth using Jackson API ObjectMapper?

Tags: jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

In Java, how to do a nested `Map<String, Object>` with unlimited depth using Jackson API ObjectMapper?

If not natively in Java, perhaps there is a 3rd party library that can handle this somewhere?

As you see here, there is casting involved.   How would I changed this code so that getting the nested `Map<String, Object>` references requires no explicit casting?

```
  @Test
  void testDeserialization_NestedMapsOnly() {

    Map<String, Object> level3Map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    level3Map.put("foo1", "31");
    level3Map.put("foo2", "32");

    Map<String, Object> level2Map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    level2Map.put("foo1", "21");
    level2Map.put("level3Map", level3Map);

    Map<String, Object> level1Map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    level1Map.put("foo1", "11");
    level1Map.put("level2Map", level2Map);

    NestedMap level0map = NestedMap.builder()
        .nestedMap(level1Map)
        .build();

    String serialized = null;
    try {
      serialized = MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(level0map);

      NestedMap nm0 = MAPPER.readValue(serialized, NestedMap.class);
      Map<String, Object> nm1 = nm0.getNestedMap();
      Map<String, Object> nm2 = (Map<String, Object>) nm1.get("level2Map");
      Map<String, Object> nm3 = (Map<String, Object>) nm2.get("level3Map");
      System.out.println(nm1);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    //System.out.println(serialized);
  }
```